# SQL Server Select query is very slow. How can I get better result?

Tags: sql-server

I've a very slow SQL query on SQL Server 2005. It takes almost 40 seconds just to do a select. After the select, I get result query and do an insert using this result. Every "textField" and "Id" is index unique and every "Id" is PK.  Please what can I do to get better results?  Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.Id, E.Id, B.Id, A.Id
FROM  
    tableA AS A 
INNER JOIN
      tableB AS B 
INNER JOIN
      tableC AS C 
INNER JOIN
      tableD AS D ON C.textField = D.textField 
INNER JOIN
      tableE AS E ON D.textField = E.textField 
   ON B.textField = D.textField 
   ON A.textField = D.textField
```

Comment: You should include at least some idea what the tables and indexes are, how many rows there are, what is the query plan and maybe also statistics io output

Comment: Add some indexes, don't join on text fields unless absolutely necessary, specify an `ON` clause for every join. Could be loads of things.

Comment: Thanks! Every "textField" and "Id" is index unique.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your query is not optimized very well at all.
For your inner joins on tables A, B and C you should have some conditions on those joins or you will get a Cartesian product on those tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Id, E.Id, B.Id, A.Id
FROM  tableA AS A INNER JOIN 
  tableB AS B **ON B.<fieldname> = <A.fieldname>** INNER JOIN
  tableC AS C **ON C.<Fieldname> = <B.FieldName>** INNER JOIN
  tableD AS D ON C.textField = D.textField INNER JOIN
  tableE AS E ON D.textField = E.textField ON B.textField = D.textField ON A.textField
```